# SQL joins to find mismatched values between two tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

If I have table 1 called "FILES" and table 2 called "Networks" and the value that goes in FILES.Network_ID must be from a list defined in Networks.Network_ID

If I wanted to run a query to find out if there are any values under network_id in table 1 that are not defined in table 2, I tried the below which doesn't work apparently...Also, I'm using the SQL view of MS ACCESS

```
SELECT *
FROM (FILES f LEFT JOIN Networks 
       ON f.Network_ID <> Networks.Network_ID)
```

Comment: Better create a relationship between Files & Networks table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
SELECT *
FROM (FILES f LEFT JOIN Networks 
       ON f.Network_ID =Networks.Network_ID)
      Where Networks.Network_ID Is Null
```

To ensure data integrity create a relationship between both tables.

[image]

Comment: The relationship is already established Santosh but I still can enter an incorrect value under Network_ID? What are your thoughts on it

Comment: @WalidMohammed Make sure `Enforce Referential Integrity` is checked.

Comment: Santosh, how can I access this dialogue box again that has the referential integrity check once the relationship is already established?

Comment: Double click on the joining line.

Answer (score 3):

This query won't work properly because your are trying to join if the ids don't match, so ideally while making join the rows will match

**For instance** if table Files contains rows with network id 1,2,3 and table Networks contains network id 1,2 then upon joining you will get a combination of rows with network ids [1,2], [2,1],[3,1],[3,2].

Instance if you use a subquery and then filter it using **IN** clause will work

```
select * from files where network_id not in (select network_id from networks);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works as charm! and yes I figured out the logic behind the different configurations in the output of my previous left join. That was so helpful.